# Sending email over One.com

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an email through a one.com mail server. With receiving one I have no problems.

however with sending I keep getting an SMTP Exception.
System.ApplicationException: 'SmtpException has occured: "failure sending mail"'

UPDATE: after a tip in the comments here is the inner Exception
WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

This is my code

```
public void email_send(string sendTo)
{
  try
     {
       MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
       msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(sendTo));
       msg.From = new MailAddress("myMail@mydomein.be", "my name");
       msg.Subject = "This is a Test Mail";
       msg.Body = "This is a test message";
       msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
       SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
       client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
       client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myMail@mydomein.be", "myPassword");
       client.Port = 587; 
       client.Host = "mailout.one.com";
       client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
       client.EnableSsl = true;
       client.Send(msg);
       Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
      }

      catch (SmtpException ex)
      {
        throw new ApplicationException
        ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         throw ex;
       }

}
```

I also have the following information form my email provider (one.com):

[image]

Comment: It would help if you told us **what the exception is**.

Comment: System.ApplicationException: 'SmtpException has occured: "failure sending mail"'

Comment: This Exception is not telling me anything that is my main problem....

Comment: Look at the InnerException too. C# SMTP do normally have useful detail in them somewhere.

Comment: @Rup you are right that does tell me more, I have updated this in the question.

Comment: It looks like you're using the correct settings - here's the same details on their help page: [Can I use your SMTP server?](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005594305-Can-I-use-your-SMTP-server-). I can't connect to it from here so I guess it's restricted to customers on their own networks. Are you connected to One at the moment, or trying to run this from a server hosted at One, or are you somewhere else? If that all looks OK I think you'll have to talk to them to ask why you're not allowed to connect.

Comment: I am not connected to there server, I am trying to do this from my home. They are recommending to use 'PHP's mail function' is this code the same but just in c#?

Comment: I don't recognise all of the client settings you've set, but this should be equivalent yes. But you're not even getting that far if the server is rejecting your connection. Can you try connecting with openssl, e.g. `openssl s_client -connect mailout.one.com:587`? (although 465 is really the right port for that) If you're on Windows you should have openssl in a git bash prompt if not elsewhere, or you could even try curl to make a simple connection: `curl -v http://mailout.one.com:587/` - it should be obvious from that if it can connect or not. If you can't connect then PHP wouldn't help.

Comment: It could also be that mailout only works from One-hosted servers, and if you're just on your home network you'll have to use send.one.com instead.

Comment: Thank you @rup you solved it!! I had to use send.one.com followed by Port 587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it looks like you can only use mailout.one.com from One.com-hosted websites - it refuses connections from elsewhere.

Instead you need to use send.one.com from other connections, which supports [the same set of ports](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005594305-Can-I-use-your-SMTP-server-).